# Ruby on Rails find_by case insensitive

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, case-insensitive

I need to find a record from 2 parameters but I need one of them to be case insensitive. The current case sensitive line is

```
  c = Course.find_by(subject_area: area, cat_number: cat)
```

But I need subject_area to be case insensitive. How would I achieve that?

Answer (score 15):

It depends on the database, and you may need to pass in db-specific SQL for that (and not use find_by).
Are you using postrges? if so, this would normally work:

```
Course.where("LOWER(subject_area) = ? AND cat_number = ?", area.downcase, cat)
```

alternatively you could convert your `subject_area` to downcase every time you save a new one... then just use:

```
Course.find_by(subject_area: area.downcase, cat_number: cat)
```

I could be wrong, but don't currently know of any rails-native way of doing a case insensitive rails `find_by`

Answer (score 9):

If you are using postgres, you could do something like:

```
> c = Course.find_by('subject_area ILIKE ? AND cat_number LIKE ?', area, cat)
```

(ILIKE is used to do insensitive search)

Answer (score 8):

An alternative can be

```
c = Course.find_by("LOWER(subject_area)= ? AND cat_number = ?", area.downcase, cat)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to have this attribute be case-insensitive then the right way is to ensure it's always one particular in your model

`before_save { self.subject_area = subject_area.downcase }`

You can migrate your existing data to be downcased as well.

Having done that your find by operation still needs to ensure that the `area` is downcased in query as suggested.
`Course.find_by(subject_area: area.downcase, cat_number: cat)`

Option 2:
I knew I was forgetting this. Let's say you dont want to go migration path. Just define a scope.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/active_record_querying.html#scopes

`scope :area_nocase, (area) -> { where("LOWER(subject_area) = ?", area.downcase) }`

then you can use it like

`Course.area_nocase(area)` or `cat.course.area_nocase(area)`
or chain it however you need to.